# Why is my for loop telling me I am converting int to bool?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, unity-game-engine

Here is my code...

```
for (int Position = 0; CardsInDeck.Length; Position++) 
{
    if (RandomlySelectedCard == CardsInDeck [Position]) 
    {
        Position = 0;
    } else {
        CardsInDeck [Position] = RandomlySelectedCard;
    }
}
```

Unity is telling me that it cannot convert int to bool, but I have checked everything and it looks good. I am making a card game by the way.

Answer (score 6):

Your for loop says:

```
for (int Position = 0; CardsInDeck.Length; Position++)
```

the second argument in the for loop is supposed to be a condition hence it should be:

```
for (int Position = 0; Position < CardsInDeck.Length; Position++)
```

Comment: @JamesBrodski Nice. Don't forget this http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: @JamesBrodski uwc.. kindly mark as the correct answer. thank you